# Subscript out of bounds error when scraping using an xpath with the rvest package

Tags: r, rvest

I am attempting to scrape a table from a website using the `rvest` package:

```
library("rvest")
uci_html <- read_html("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html")
uci_data <- uci_html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath="/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]") %>%
  html_table()
uci_data <- uci_data[[1]]
```

As far as all the examples I have seen, the format I am using should work, however `R` is not scraping any data and as a result I am getting the error:

> Error in uci_data[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

Do you know why this might be the case and what I can do to scrape the data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand it but it looks like the tbody is unnecessary.

```
library("rvest")
uci_html <- read_html("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html")
uci_data <- uci_html %>%
   html_nodes(xpath="/html/body/table[2]/tr/td[2]/table[2]") %>% html_table( fill=TRUE)
uci_data <- uci_data[[1]]
```

Another way using the html tags is:

```
tables<-uci_html %>% html_nodes("table") 
html_table(tables[6], fill=TRUE)[[1]]
```

In order to identify that the sixth table was the table of interest, it involve some trial and error but I find using the html tags easier than the xpath form.